# How to define a curve surrounding the origin?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analytic-geometry, curves

Is there any criteria for stating that a curve is sorrounding the origin?

---

For example:
Consider $\Bbb D=\{x^2+y^2-y\le\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\}$, that is in polar coordinates: $\Bbb D_{(\rho, \theta)}=\{0\le\theta\le2\pi,\, 0\le\rho\le1+\sin{\theta}\}$.
In particular it's $\{0\le\theta\le2\pi\}$ because the curve $\{x^2+y^2=y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\}$ surrounds the origin; and I stated that thinking "**it is the locus of points $(x,y)$ which are away from the origin** $\left(y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$".

---

Now, I think that a similiar condition could be a right answer in these cases; but is there a more general condition about?

---

**[EDIT]**
Maybe the true question was: "when a curve given into cartesian form can be written into $\{0 \le \theta \le 2\pi, 0 \le \rho \le f(\theta)\}$ for some function $f$"?

Comment: Isn’t the origin actually **on** that curve? What do you think “surrounding” ought to mean, intuitively?

Comment: @DavidK you're right.. a curve that is closed and simple could be enough for my necessities.. I don't mind if the origin is on the curve for some points.. I'm searching of conditions to write $0\le\theta\le2\pi$ whitout any problems.

Comment: Why not write $(0,0)\in \mathbb D$?

Comment: Merely knowing that a curve is simple and closed and the origin is on or inside the curve, you still cannot guarantee that you can write your domain using a single function of $\theta$ as you seem to desire. It is possible for a non-convex simple closed curve to cross the same ray from the origin multiple times.

Comment: @DavidK What did you intend with " to cross the same ray from the origin multiple times"?... intuitively I guess "NOT" cross the same ray multiple times...

Comment: Can we include calculus tag?

Comment: @Narasimham sure!

Comment: Another word for a region whose boundary can be described as a one-to-one function of angle is "star-shaped".

Comment: @aschepler Can you give me more infos?

Answer (score 2):

This will probably not be the answer you are looking for.
I don't think a correct answer of the kind you are looking for exists.
But explaining this requires more than will fit into comments.

---

Consider this simple closed curve that contains the origin.

[image]

It is the algebraic curve given by
$\left((x-1)^2+(y-.3)^{2}+1\right)^2-4(x-1)^2=1.03$,
which is an oval of Cassini whose center has been displaced from the origin.

Notice that the curve crosses the positive $x$-axis three times.

This curve and its interior include the origin, so it is true that in every direction
$\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ from the origin there is some point of the curve.
There are even three points in some directions.

It is also true that the curve encloses a finite region of the plane.
But you will not be able to describe that region as
$\mathbb D_{(\rho, \theta)}=\{0\le\theta\le2\pi,\, 0\le\rho\leq f(\theta)\}$
for any function $f.$

If what you want is a region that can be described in the form
$\{0\le\theta\le2\pi,\, 0\le\rho\leq f(\theta)\}$ for some function $f,$
why not just say so?
Why do you need to state any other conditions?

---

If you don't actually care about writing a domain in such a form
(that is, if the domain in the question was not actually relevant to the question),
and all you actually want is that a curve be simple, closed, and contain the origin either in the interior of the curve or on the curve itself, why not just say so?
Why do you need to state any other conditions?

Merely knowing that a curve is the locus of points $(x,y)$ that are at a distance $(p(x,y))^{1/2}$ from the origin for some polynomial $p$
is not enough to conclude that the curve contains the origin.
For example, the boundary of the region shown below is a curve that is the locus of points $(x,y)$ that are $\left(x^2+y^2-2y+\frac12\right)^{1/2}$ away from the origin, but it clearly does not contain the origin.

[image]

---

In summary, don't make things pointlessly complicated.

Comment: I understood that I complicated things more than needed.. Eventually, I meant when a region can be described in the form $\{0 \le \theta \le 2\pi, 0 \le \rho \le f(\theta)\}$ for some function $f$

Comment: I think that is exactly what to write. It is the least complicated way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

For  a circle constant $C$ also known as ***power*** should be negative ( zero if on circle)

$$ x^2+y^2 + a x + b y + C = 0$$

So also an ellipse will enclose the origin when $C<0$ in:

$$a x^2 +2h x y+b y^2+2 f x+2 g y + C=0. $$

Considering pole/polar of an oval, "tangent length" from origin is imaginary.

This is easier with differential calculus than with analytical geometry, if allowed here.

An oval curve polar coordinates $ r= f(\theta) $ has derivative $ r^{'}$. If

$$\sin \psi= \dfrac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+r^{'2}}} $$

is positive everywhere then the curve contains/encloses the origin. The  $\psi$ is radius vector to polar curve angle.

Polar plots of a Newton ellipse ( semi latus-rectum $p=1$, eccentricity $e= 0.6$ )

$$\dfrac{p}{r}= 1- e \cos\theta $$

Differentiate with respect to arc $s\; \frac{dr}{ds}=\cos \psi , \frac{d\theta}{ds}=\frac{\sin \psi}{r}$ we get

$$\tan\psi= \frac{\cos \theta-1/e}{\sin \theta}$$

$\sin \psi$  is everywhere positive and the polar plot also seen to contain the focus or origin
[image: Curve contains origin]

Basically we should *use differential equations* to find how the pole aspects portions of a closed loop curve. Whether pole is  included or excluded in a loop can be seen by intersection of $(\sin \psi, s)$ curves with arc-length x-axis.We are concerned with the roots.

*Behaviour of first curve* is like Newton's ellipse  where $\sin \psi$ is always positive.

The second curve behaves differently with alternating arc segments with positive and negative $\sin \psi$ which can be exemplified using the eccentric circle ( chosen because it is the simplest closed curve) given below with *two tangent points*.

Property of Circle product of segments $ OA \cdot OB=T^2 $ can be written:

$$ 2a \sin \psi= (1-T^2/a^2) $$

The appearance of points of tangency demarcating regions of sign change of $\sin\psi$ is in itself a proof of the pole existing outside the loop of curve. The situation of pole/polar is evident for external pole.

[image]

EDIT1:

Two example where curvature involves $\sin \psi$ are given taking the above further :

***Eccentric Circles :*** $n=1$; Constant curvature
$$ \dfrac{d\psi}{ds} +\dfrac{(\sin \psi)^1}{r} = \pm 1/a; \; $$
***Precessing Orbits:***$\; n=2 $
$$ \dfrac{d\psi}{ds} +\dfrac{(\sin \psi)^n}{r} = \pm 1/a; \; $$

The plots show how in two precession orbits cases $\sin \psi $ influences inclusion or exclusion of the pole/origin.

[image: Ecc Circle & Orbits of precession]

Comment: It's a good information to me.. but maybe I didn't understand very well my own problem before to ask the question... As @DavidK noticed, my question was more on the possibility to write a domain like $\{g(x,y)\le0\}$ into the form $\{0 \le \theta \le 2\pi, 0 \le \rho \le f(\theta)\}$ for some function $f$... I'm really sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: Your question in plain English is: "When does my polar graph include the origin?"... right?

Comment: Originally yes, because I gave for sure that: "if a curve enclose the origin, then in polar form it can be write like $\{ 0 \le \theta \le 2\pi, {...} \}$". But, @DavidK showed me that is not true..

Answer (score 1):

Using complex number as coordinates:

\begin{align}
  z &= re^{i\theta} \\
  dz &= (r'+ri) e^{i\theta} d\theta
\end{align}

By [Cauchy integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula):

$$f(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z-a} \, dz$$

where $C$ is a simple closed curve enclosing $a\in \mathbb{C}$ in anti-clockwise sense.

In particular, take $a=0$ and $f(z)=1$ with contour $C=\partial D$ (boundary of an [open set](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/OpenSet.html) $D$),

$$\oint_{\partial D} \frac{dz}{z}=
\begin{cases}
 2\pi i, & 0\in D \\
 0, & 0\notin D
\end{cases}$$

You may regard this as two-dimensional [Gauss' Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law).  Please feel free to refer my two-dimensional treatment on electric field in [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/382905/electric-field-lines/383068#383068).

See also [winding number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number), which is relevant to simple closed curve, for your further interest.