# How do you write a contour in polar coordinates that covers all and only $z \in \{\Re(z) \in [c-a, c+a] \}$, but $ \Im(z) \in [-b,b] $?

Tags: contour-integration, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to do contour integration, but I need it over a specific subset of complex numbers $z$. Specifically, I need a contour that, for real numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$, it covers all and only $z \in \{ \Re(z) \in [c-a, c+a] \}$, but for all $z$ in the contour, $\Im(z) \in [-b,b] $. I also need it to be in polar form, that is, all points on $r(\theta)$, with $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$, describe the boundary of the contour.

I'm basically asking for an ellipse that has radius $a$ on the real line, radius $b$ on the imaginary line and the center at $c+0i$.

Comment: A circle with centre at $(c,0)$ and radius $\ge \sqrt{a2+b^2}$ satisfies your conditions.

Comment: @Bernard Whoops, I meant intersection, not union.

Comment: Yes, that's how I undersood it.  $z$ belongs to a rectangle with centre at $(c,0)$.

Comment: @Bernard But then a circle wouldn't work. It would enclose more than it should.

Comment: It wasn't clear from your initial post, or I misread it. In this case, consider the sides of the rectangle.

Comment: @Bernard I'm confused. What do you mean?

Comment: You should write the polar equation of the rectangle defined by your conditions.

Comment: @Bernard Well, I don't know how to do that, hence the question.

Comment: The polar equation of a vertical line is not very hard: the projection on the $x$-axis is constant, and for horizontal lines, it's the projection on the $y$-axis which is constant. The most delicate point, in my opinion, is to determine the bounds of the polar angle for each side of the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

In Cartesian coordinates:

$$\frac{(x-c)^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

Substitute $(x,y)=r(\cos \theta,\sin \theta)$ and solve $r$,

$$r_{\pm}(\theta)=
\frac{b^2 c\cos \theta \pm
      ab\sqrt{(a^2-c^2) \sin^2 \theta+b^2\cos^2 \theta}}
     {a^2\sin^2 \theta+b^2\cos^2 \theta}$$

A plot of $r$ vs $\theta$ when $(a,b,c)=(5,4,3)$ such that $a>c>0$

[image]

and the corresponding ellipse:

[image]

A plot of $r$ vs $\theta$ when $(a,b,c)=(3,4,5)$ such that $c>a>0$

[image]

and the corresponding ellipse:

[image]

**Further points to be noticed:**

Given $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$, the contour with continuous $\theta$ should enclose the origin.  In this case, the mapping $\theta \mapsto r$ is surjective.

Now $0\in [c-a,c+a]$,

$$a> |c| \ge 0$$

See also [another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3741569/how-to-define-a-curve-surrounding-the-origin/3745402#3745402) of mine.

In particular, $c$ is the linear eccentricity, that is

$$a=\frac{b}{\sqrt{1-e^2}}=\frac{c}{e}=\sqrt{b^2+c^2}$$

Then

$$r(\theta)=\frac{b^2}{a-c\cos \theta}$$

Comment: $c$ is the x-coordinate of the center of the ellipse: on the x-y plane, the center would be $(c,0)$, on the Re-Im plane, it would be $c+0i$

Comment: Answer revised.

Comment: Why must the origin be enclosed in the contour?

Comment: You define $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$.  If $(0,0)$ outside the contour, some $\theta$ values will be missing.  See also the link of another answer of mine.